# how can i return String value from list by it's name value in dart list

Tags: string, flutter, dart, widget, return

How can i handle the following code

```
List books = ['book1', book2]

String getTextWidget() {
     return // here i need to only return the element which is 'book1'   such as if books.contains('book1') return this element as String  ;
  }
```

the i need to put it in Text Widget like so

```
Container(
child Text(getTextWidget())
)
```

i tried the following code , it is work but it does not accept String Widget

```
 getTextWidget() {
    books .forEach((element) {
      if(element.contains('book1')){
        'book1'
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "such as .contains('book1') ;" ? Do you want to return '.contains('book1')' as a String value? Please review and edit your post and make sure you have used Quotations correctly in your post text

Comment: my question is correct as well !!!!!!!

Comment: What is `book2` ? is it a String value? is it a variable? The result of `books.contains('book1')` is a Boolean value, What do you want to return as String?

Comment: Your question is incomprehensible: `books.contains('book1')` returns a boolean type and your function `getTextWidget` returns a String type. Explain more clearly please.

Comment: i didn't make it as release !! .. there is a '//'  before .contains .. which i need to return the element which contains 'book1' , so now after you understand the question lemme see answers! \ :

Comment: If you want `getTextWidget` to return the `String` `'book1`' if `books.contains('book1')`, then you can do `String getTextWidget() { return books.contains('book1') ? 'book1' : ''; }`.  However, your question is underspecified; you don't explain what should happen if `books` does not contain `'book1'`, and `getTextWidget` doesn't seem very useful.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd benefit from the `.firstWhere` method on your list.

```dart
void main() {
  // an arbitrary object that is not type String
  final book2 = Object(); 
  List books = ['book1', book2];
  print(getTextElement(books)); // book1
}

String? getTextElement(List list) {
  return list.firstWhere((e) => e is String);
}
```

Comment: yes but what if the wanted element wasn't in the first index ! , since i need to find it by it's value name object

Comment: The above will work if it's not in the first index. What do you mean by "value name object"?

Answer (score -3):

try this , give "book1" to the methode as a parameter

```
String getTextWidget(String nameofbook) {
 if(books.contains(nameofbook)==true){
 return nameofbook;
 }
 else return null;
}
```

Comment: This code is not going to work... book2 is an Object and not a String. "String getTextWidget" can't even return null because is not optional/nullable and "contains" already return a boolean which is a redundant logic adding the == true.

Comment: lest say object return then :D